# Drawing directed edges with arrow in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I try to show a directed graph to show a temporal evolution of a phenomenon. This is a part of my code:

```
        path.links.0 {
        stroke: red;
    }

    path.links.1 {
        stroke: green;
    }

    marker#0 {
        stroke: #999;
        fill: #999;
    }

    marker#1 {
        stroke: #999;
        fill: #999;
    }
```

and

```
                            svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
                            //.data(json.links)
                            .data(["1","0"])                                    
                            .enter().append("svg:marker")
                                .attr("id", String)
                                .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
                                .attr("refX", 15)
                                .attr("refY", -1.5)
                                .attr("markerWidth", 6)
                                .attr("markerHeight", 6)
                                .attr("orient", "auto")
                              .append("svg:path")
                                .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

                        var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
                            .data(force.links())
                            .enter().append("svg:path")
                                .style("stroke", function(d) { return fillLine(0); }) //only one color GRAY
                                .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return 2; }) //weight of marker
                                .style("stroke-dasharray", //here we select 0 = plain line; 5 = dotted line 
                                    function(d) { 
                                        if (d.type == 0) { 
                                            return lineType(d.type) //using lineType defined above
                                        } else { 
                                            return lineType(d.type) 
                                        }; 
                                    })
                                //.style("fill", "red")
                                .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
                                .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")";
                                //.attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#triangle)"; 
                                });
```

My problem: I can't show the arrows... only a line. I try many styles and many lines of code but I can't show the end of path (triangle).
Please, can you help me?
Best regards.

Comment: What is `d.type` returning?  AFAICT, for your code to work it will need to return `marker#0` or `marker#1`.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I'm playing around with the same piece of code and having the same issues, though I believe the marker-end URL I am setting is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your "marker-end" attribute should refer to the ID or other CSS selector of the marker. As it stands, you define your markers with an "id" of String, which doesn't correspond to the url() selector you're referencing on your svg:path's "marker-end".